# PHP: Login with curl to aspx

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I'm trying to login to one page programmed in ASP.NET (Pages of my school, they haven't mobile version and it's very bad on mobile, so i'm trying load any information to my web.)

Login is OK, but the page doesn't load whole. Only header.

I haven't idea why.

There is script (it's from http://www.mishainthecloud.com/):

```
    <?php
// urls to call - the login page and the secured page
$urlLogin = "http://bakalari.gymtce.cz/bakaweb/login.aspx";
$urlSecuredPage = "http://bakalari.gymtce.cz/bakaweb/prehled.aspx?s=2";

// POST names and values to support login
$nameUsername='ctl00$cphmain$TextBoxjmeno';       // the name of the username textbox on the login form
$namePassword='ctl00$cphmain$TextBoxHeslo';       // the name of the password textbox on the login form
$nameLoginBtn='ctl00$cphmain$ButtonPrihlas';          // the name of the login button (submit) on the login form
$valUsername ='xxx';        // the value to submit for the username
$valPassword ='xxx';        // the value to submit for the password
$valLoginBtn ='';             // the text value of the login button itself

// the path to a file we can read/write; this will
// store cookies we need for accessing secured pages
$cookies = 'cookie.txt';

// regular expressions to parse out the special ASP.NET
// values for __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION
$regexViewstate = '/__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';
$regexEventVal  = '/__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';


/************************************************
* utility function: regexExtract
*    use the given regular expression to extract
*    a value from the given text;  $regs will
*    be set to an array of all group values
*    (assuming a match) and the nthValue item
*    from the array is returned as a string
************************************************/
function regexExtract($text, $regex, $regs, $nthValue)
{
if (preg_match($regex, $text, $regs)) {
 $result = $regs[$nthValue];
}
else {
 $result = "";
}
return $result;
}



/************************************************
* initialize a curl handle; we'll use this
*   handle throughout the script
************************************************/
$ch = curl_init();


/************************************************
* first, issue a GET call to the ASP.NET login
*   page.  This is necessary to retrieve the
*   __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION values
*   that the server issues
************************************************/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$data=curl_exec($ch);

// from the returned html, parse out the __VIEWSTATE and
// __EVENTVALIDATION values
$viewstate = regexExtract($data,$regexViewstate,$regs,1);
$eventval = regexExtract($data, $regexEventVal,$regs,1);


/************************************************
* now issue a second call to the Login page;
*   this time, it will be a POST; we'll send back
*   as post data the __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION
*   values the server previously sent us, as well as the
*   username/password.  We'll also set up a cookie
*   jar to retrieve the authentication cookie that
*   the server will generate and send us upon login.
************************************************/
$postData = '__VIEWSTATE='.rawurlencode($viewstate)
          .'&__EVENTVALIDATION='.rawurlencode($eventval)
          .'&'.$nameUsername.'='.$valUsername
          .'&'.$namePassword.'='.$valPassword
          .'&'.$nameLoginBtn.'='.$valLoginBtn
          ;

curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);     

$data = curl_exec($ch);


/************************************************
* with the authentication cookie in the jar,
* we'll now issue a GET to the secured page;
* we set curl's COOKIEFILE option to the same
* file we used for the jar before to ensure the
* authentication cookie is sent back to the
* server
************************************************/
curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlSecuredPage);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);     

$data = curl_exec($ch);

// at this point the secured page may be parsed for
// values, or additional POSTS made to submit parameters
// and retrieve data.  For this sample, we'll just
// echo the results.
echo $data;



/************************************************
* that's it! Close the curl handle
************************************************/
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

I did not put the login code is too long and confusing.. It's available on the URL from the script ..

But i think, that the bug is maybe because of one script from secured page

This:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['formbaka'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.formbaka;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Thank you and sorry for my english.

//

I edit part of code like this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
$data=curl_exec($ch);

// from the returned html, parse out the __VIEWSTATE and
// __EVENTVALIDATION values
$viewstate = regexExtract($data,$regexViewstate,$regs,1);
$eventval = regexExtract($data, $regexEventVal,$regs,1);


/************************************************
* now issue a second call to the Login page;
*   this time, it will be a POST; we'll send back
*   as post data the __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION
*   values the server previously sent us, as well as the
*   username/password.  We'll also set up a cookie
*   jar to retrieve the authentication cookie that
*   the server will generate and send us upon login.
************************************************/
$postData = '__LASTFOCUS='
          .'&__EVENTTARGET='
          .'&__EVENTARGUMENT='
          .'&__VIEWSTATE='.rawurlencode($viewstate) 
          .'&'.$nameUsername.'='.$valUsername
          .'&'.$namePassword.'='.$valPassword
          .'&'.$nameLoginBtn.'='.$valLoginBtn
          .'&popupWS=0%3A0%3A-1%3A-10000%3A-10000%3A0%3A200px%3A100px%3A1%3A0%3A0%3A0'
          .'&ctl00%24popup%24checklexpredmety=U'     
          .'&DXScript=1_145%2C1_81%2C1_137%2C1_92%2C1_78%2C1_130%2C1_128%2C1_99%2C1_95'

          ;
```

Here is image with POST from official app - [link](http://holicz.eu/content/images/post.JPG)

Comment: Please add an example of the POST headers sent in a normal request so we can help you. They could also be checking 'USER_AGENT' HTTP header on the request too.

Comment: Ok. In question is now new code and image from Tamper Data (only without nick and pass).

I found, that my script has many request to DXR.axd and to WebResource.axd with status 404. In official app is status "pending"

Comment: I can see there is an ASP.NET session cookie, which is being sent along with the POST data. It is possible when you first GET the login page (to view it), it creates a SESSION key which it checks when you POST. Try adding the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile) line to the first 'urlLogin' GET request too, so the cookie is set before the POST.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. But I found out a few things. First: curl does not send __LASTFOCUS (or at least does not show in div aspNetHidden). Second: Some informations are in source code, but not show at page. I think, that may be related with DXR.axd. I don't know what is it, but in source code lode from it many css files, from links like DXR.axd?r=1_X-Hsjh7 (where X is a number, 1,2,3,4,7 or 8). I don't know how i can create this file, because DXR.axd is empty and with variable is probably generated dynamically. And third: Some pages load without trouble, so I think, that here is some

Comment: protection. But I don't know what. But sincerely I think that is may be related with DXR.axd.

Comment: Did you add the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile) line to the first 'urlLogin' GET request? It will be using a variation of [CSRF protection like this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/)

Comment: Yep, I tried this. But unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: Any progress on this? I have a the same problem.

Comment: /Any progress on this ?!  I can't solve this